# How to add Sublime Text 3 command line support for Mac OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, command-line, sublimetext3, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to get to work again Sublime Text 3 on El Capitan - OSX.

I already created the symlink with this

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

I used to run Sublime like this

```
~/myproject/subl .
```

Now if I run the same line Sublime opens, but not the folder where I am stepped at. In other words, it opens Sublime, but the dot parameter does not seem to do anything.

Here is an image to show my problem

[image]

Any idea where it could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: How can this `~/myproject/subl` open Sublime?

Comment: @Thomas thank you. The main idea is you have a symlink to sublime which you created with the the command in the question, then the dot is a parameter where you said open sublime with this folder. the '~/myproject/' folder was only an example that I would open my projects like that. :)

Comment: I know, I know. But, I doubt that you have a symlink named `subl` in `~/myproject/` (but maybe I missed important information :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `~/myproject/subl` likely does not exist, so your command will fail. To open `~/myproject` in Sublime, simply enter

```
subl ~/myproject
```

and the folder will open. If you're already in `~/myproject`, `subl .` will do the same thing.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried and did not work, it happens the same as if I execute "subl ." opens sublime but not the tree folders, as it use to do in yosemite.

Comment: @agusgambina So, say you're in the `~/myproject` folder in Terminal, and you execute `subl .` - what actually opens in Sublime?

Comment: As I updated in the question with the image it opens sublime but with no files or folder on the left pane. Thank you @MattDMo for your answer.

Comment: Unlike Windows, UNIX systems don't look in the current working directory when executing a command.  So unless the current directory is in `$PATH`, the normal method of invoking a command in the current directory is to use `./name_of_executable` (in this case `./subl`).

Comment: @trojanfoe the `subl` command is working just fine. It's just that Sublime isn't opening the current folder when `subl .` is executed.

Comment: @agusgambina does `subl README` work as expected in that directory?

Comment: @MattDMo thank you for your answer, it does not work, it does the same, opens but without anything.

Comment: @agusgambina There's probably something wrong with your `subl` command. Before we fix that, though, what is the result of running `which -a subl`?

Comment: @MattDMo the result of 'which -a subl' is '/usr/local/bin/subl'

Comment: @agusgambina OK, that's good. Please run `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/subl`, then [redownload](http://sublimetext.com/3) Sublime and drag it to your `/Applications` folder, hitting `replace` if it asks you (make sure you *completely* quit Sublime before doing this!). Then, rerun the `sudo ln -s ...` command you have in your question. Finally, completely quit tmux and Terminal, then open it up again and see if the `subl .` command works as expected.

Comment: @MattDMo thank you, it worked, but definitely the problem is with tmux, when I am running tmux it does not work, regard this I will mark this as the correct answer.